# task.Container moving from docker to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, coredns

I'm trying to bring docker container to kubernetes. In docker you can ask the *dns* for :

```
host tasks.containername
```

The result are all internal IPs from running containers with this name.

I do the same on kubernetes, by using the headless-services. I can do

```
host pod-name
```

The result are also all internal IPs from the pods.

So far so good but there are a lot of "run.sh" scripts that uses the "task.XXX" query. Have someone a idea how to fix this without editing all run.sh scripts ?

Maybe something in the coredns, with mapping.

best and thank you

Answer (score 1):

I agree with editing the scripts is the wisest solution, but here is how you can edit coredns in kubernetes.

`kubectl edit configmap coredns -n kube-system`

and then add the rewrite config as below.

```
rewrite name tasks.containername.default.svc.cluster.local containername.default.svc.cluster.local
```

for example

```
.:53 {
    errors
    log
    health
    rewrite name tasks.containername.default.svc.cluster.local containername.default.svc.cluster.local
    kubernetes cluster.local 10.0.0.0/24
    proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
    cache 30
}
```

And then reload coredns as below

`kubectl exec -n kube-system coredns-xxxxxxx -- kill -SIGUSR1 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think editing them is the wisest solution.

For sake of clarity, it's not `host pod-name` but `host headless-service`